# How can I have my token accept numbers with decimals

Tags: java, regex, token

```
if (tokens[i].matches("[0-9]+"))
```

This makes it currently only read whole integers until a space occurs, how do I make it read decimals as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an optional decimal part:

```
if (tokens[i].matches("[0-9]*([.][0-9]+)?"))
```

Use asterisk to make the integer portion optional. The problem with this expression, however, that now it could match an empty string. A better (but longer) expression would match a string that starts in a decimal point in a separate subexpression, as follows:

```
if (tokens[i].matches("[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?|[.][0-9]+"))
```

Comment: would that work if i wanted to start the number with a decimal? also what is the "?" for

Comment: @user3427042 Change `[0-9]+` (1 or more) to `[0-9]*` (0 or more) for the integer portion.

Comment: @user3427042 Question mark after an expression makes the preceding expression optional. In this case, `[.][0-9]+` is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (tokens[i].matches([0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?)
```

Comment: That's good for only two decimal points. PS: You're missing the quotes.